# window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight not working on iOS

Tags: javascript

On iOS devices the following results in 0 for the width and height.

It works fine on Android devices and my browser.

Anyone know why it doesn't work on iOS devices?

```
function setWidth() {

   var outWindowWidth = window.outerWidth;
   var outWindowHeight = window.outerHeight;

   alert("Outer Width: " + outWindowWidth + "\nOuter Height: " + outWindowHeight);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue since iOS 8. Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed to know.

The window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight DOM properties always return 0. Other DOM properties will need to be used instead. This may affect websites that use leaf.js.